# How to target div nested in a link

Tags: css

I have an HTML code that wraps a link around a div.

Before I wrapped the link I was able to target the divs with the CSS nth-of-type, but since i wrapped the link HTML code around, it doesnt work anymore, presumably as they are now "nested"?

How would I have to amend my CSS to still target them?

Thanks so much!

**EXAMPLE:**

In this example divs 3,4,5 should all have different sizes than sp-submenu-item (50px), which isnt the case.

```css
/* START: UNnecceary code for question */
.sp-submenu-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1%;
  justify-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: start;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.sp-submenu-item {
margin-top: 25px;
width: 50px;
background-color: #646464;
border: 1px solid white;
border-radius: 5px;
color: white;
font-family: 'Caveat', cursive;
font-size: 20px;
text-transform: uppercase;
white-space: nowrap;
height: 35px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 2px black;
}
/* END: UNnecceary code for question */

.sp-submenu-item:nth-of-type(3), .sp-submenu-item:nth-of-type(4) {
  width: 220px;
}
.sp-submenu-item:nth-of-type(5) {
  width: 125px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sp-submenu-wrapper">
<a href="#"><div class="sp-submenu-item">menu 1</div></a>
<a href="#"><div class="sp-submenu-item">menu 2</div></a>
<a href="#"><div class="sp-submenu-item">menu 3</div></a>
<a href="#"><div class="sp-submenu-item">menu 4</div></a>
<a href="#"><div class="sp-submenu-item">menu 5</div></a>
</div>
```

Comment: move the nth-of-type to the `a` element

Comment: Try `.sp-submenu-item a:nth-of-type(3)` or `.sp-submenu-item a:nth-of-type(3) div`

Comment: Thank you both! I figured out that I need to target first the wrapper (no the item class) then the "a" with nth type and then the div, i.e. just in the logical sequence as the code is done, so it's: ".sp-submenu-wrapper a:nth-of-type(3) div {"